# Generating Samples at Points used in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

For one of my academic courses, i need to generate sample lattices and was wondering if there was any way to generalize the hard-coded points I am using. Instead of repeating `-5.19,-3.46,-1.73,0,1.73,3.46,5.19` all the time, is there a way to define a macro or equivalent.

```
    \documentclass{standalone}

    \usepackage{tikz}

    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{width=5.5in,compat=1.10}
    \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
      xmin=-6, xmax=6,
            ymin=-6,ymax=6,
                    xlabel = $x$,
                    ylabel = $y$]
    \addplot [->, thick,  red]
            coordinates { (0,0) (sqrt(3),1)} node[above right,pos=1] {$v_1$};
    \addplot [->, thick,  blue]
            coordinates { (0,0) (0,2)} node[above right,pos=1] {$v_2$};

    \addplot+ [mark=none,black] table {
    0.5 1
    -0.5 1
    -1 0
    -0.5 -1 
    0.5 -1
    1 0
    0.5 1
    };

    \addplot[only marks, mark=o, samples at={-5.19,-3.46,-1.73,0,1.73,3.46,5.19}]{-0.55*x + 2};
    \addplot[only marks, mark=o, samples at={-5.19,-3.46,-1.73,0,1.73,3.46,5.19}]{-0.55*x-2};

    \addplot[only marks, mark=o, samples at={-5.19,-3.46,-1.73,0,1.73,3.46,5.19}]{-0.55*x-4};
    \addplot[only marks, mark=o, samples at={-5.19,-3.46,-1.73,0,1.73,3.46,5.19}]{-0.55*x+4};

    \addplot[only marks, mark=o, samples at={-5.19,-3.46,-1.73,0,1.73,3.46,5.19}]{-0.55*x-6};

    \addplot[only marks, mark=o, samples at={-5.19,-3.46,-1.73,0,1.73,3.46,5.19}]{-0.55*x+6};

    \addplot[only marks, mark=o, samples at={-5.19,-3.46,-1.73,0,1.73,3.46,5.19}]{-0.55*x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, with \pgfplotsinvokeforeach ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a loop. (Of course there are even simpler ways to create such lattices.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{width=5.5in,compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
  xmin=-6, xmax=6,
        ymin=-6,ymax=6,
                xlabel = $x$,
                ylabel = $y$]
\addplot [->, thick,  red]
        coordinates { (0,0) (sqrt(3),1)} node[above right,pos=1] {$v_1$};
\addplot [->, thick,  blue]
        coordinates { (0,0) (0,2)} node[above right,pos=1] {$v_2$};

\addplot+ [mark=none,black] table {
0.5 1
-0.5 1
-1 0
-0.5 -1 
0.5 -1
1 0
0.5 1
};
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-6,-4,...,6}{
\addplot[only marks, mark=o, samples
at={-5.19,-3.46,-1.73,0,1.73,3.46,5.19}]{-0.55*x + #1};}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]